# Date conditional update issue SSIS?

Tags: ssis

I have an issue in SSIS conditional split. The condition update will update forever whenever I  run the package.

In my table table i have a column date_mod which change if the personne change the data. However i have it null if it hasn't change.  so the problem comes from comparing null  from the source table  to null from the destination table, or sometime both have null ?

```
!ISNULL(id) && !ISNULL(sourceId) && (id == sourceId) && (date_mod != date_mod_dw)
```

Do you kow how to solve this issue ?

[image: conditional split formula]

[image: example table]

Comment: Cast NULL to a fixed date such as 2999-01-01. Then I suggest you stop using SSIS for this and start using T-SQL

Answer (score 0):

Try to change NULL date_mode values by a dump value in your T-SQL query using

```
 SELECT col1, col2,.., ISNULL( date_mod ,'1999-12-31') AS date_mod  FROM yourTable
```

And then in your conditional split keep the following:

```
!ISNULL(id) && !ISNULL(sourceId) && (id == sourceId) && (date_mod != date_mod_dw)
```

Or you can replace the NULL values for `date_mode` using a Derived Column to apply the condition to `date_mod` :

```
(ISNULL([date_mod]) ? (DT_DATE)"1999-12-31" : [date_mod]))
```

Then :

```
!ISNULL(id) && !ISNULL(sourceId) && (id == sourceId) && (date_mod != date_mod_dw)
```

This is my assumption :

You need to handle the null values in SSIS conditional split as SSIS will treat the entire condition as NULL if there are null values in the conditions.

Due to this, your entire condition was returned NULL